# What do we mean by this Numpy shape?

Tags: python, numpy

I came across this Python statement, but couldn't understand what it means, especially the part between parentheses:

```
np.zeros(1+x.shape[1])
```

I tried to mimic its behavior by a simple example, but got a `tuple index out of range` error.

Can you clarify what the parameters mean for the above array? An example would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means: Create a 1D numpy array with zeros whose length is equal to one more than the number of columns in the numpy array `x`.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,1],[3,4,5]])
>>> print a.shape
(2L, 3L)
>>> b = np.zeros(1+a.shape[1])
>>> print b
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

`b` will have size equal to `1+(number of cols in a)` = `1+3` = `4`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a toy code that can help you understand better

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> x.shape
(2, 3)
>>> x.shape[1]
3
>>> np.zeros(1+x.shape[1])
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

`x.shape` returns the shape of the array as a tuple `(no of rows, no of columns)` in this case `(2, 3)`. `x.shape[1]` is therefore the number of the columns in the array. A new array filled with zeros (`np.zeros(...)`) is created using the given dimension: `1+3`